# Python Regular Expression Extract Lookahead

Tags: python, regex

I have been trying to extract transport node names and location coordinate strings from a webpage scrape (that I have permission to scrape). The names and locations are in cdata blocks of javascript. See here: http://pastebin.com/6Vtup2dE

Using regular expressions in python

```
re.findall("(?:\(new\sMicrosoft\.Maps\.Location\()(.+?(?=\)\,))(?:.+?(?=new\ssimpleInfo\(\\\'))(.+?(?=\\)))", test_str)
```

I get

```
[(u'55.86527,-4.2517133',
  u"new simpleInfo('Buchanan Bus Station','Glasgow, Buchanan Bus Station - entrance to station is situated on Killermont Street. It is a short walk from George Square and within easy reach of Glasgow?s main shopping and leisure areas. Please check the bus station passenger displays for stance information for megabus services.'"),
 (u'55.86068,-4.257852', u"new simpleInfo('Central Train Station',''"),
 (u'51.492653,-0.14765126',
  u"new simpleInfo('Victoria, Buckingham Palace Rd, Stop 10','London Victoria, Buckingham Palace Road - at the corner of Elizabeth Bridge and diagonally across from the main entrance to Victoria Coach Station. megabus Oxford Tube services leave from Stop 10.'"),
 (u'51.492596,-0.14985295',
  u"new simpleInfo('Victoria Coach Station','London Victoria Coach Station is situated on Buckingham Palace Rd at the junction with Elizabeth St. megabus services depart from Stands 15-20, located in the departures area of North West terminal '"),
 (u'51.503437,-0.112076715',
  u"new simpleInfo('Waterloo Train Station','London Waterloo - London Waterloo Station is located on Station Approach, SE1 London - just behind the London Eye. The station is a terminus for trains serving the south-west of England and Eurostar services. Waterloo is the largest station in the UK by area. Its spacious, curved concourse is lined with shops and all the modern amenities.\\n'"),
 (u'51.53062,-0.12585254',
  u"new simpleInfo('St Pancras International Train Station','For East Midlands Trains services only. London St Pancras International, London - St Pancras Station is located on Pancras Rd NW1 between the national Library and Kings Cross station. The station is the terminus for trains serving East Midlands and South Yorkshire. It is also the new London terminal for the Eurostar services to the continent. Kings Cross St Pancras tube station provides links via the London underground to other London destinations.'"),
 (u'51.52678,-0.13297649',
  u"new simpleInfo('Euston Train Station','For Virgin Trains Services Only. London Euston - The station is the main terminal for trains to London from the West Midlands and North West England. It is connected to Euston Tube Station for easy access to the London Underground network'"),
 (u'51.52953,-0.12506014',
  u"new simpleInfo('St Pancras, Coach Road','In some instances megabusplus services which operate as coach only will pick up from Coach Road, outside London St Pancras.'"),
 (u'55.86527,-4.2517133',
  u"new simpleInfo('Buchanan Bus Station','Glasgow, Buchanan Bus Station - entrance to station is situated on Killermont Street. It is a short walk from George Square and within easy reach of Glasgow?s main shopping and leisure areas. Please check the bus station passenger displays for stance information for megabus services.'"),
 (u'55.86068,-4.257852', u"new simpleInfo('Central Train Station',''")]
```

But what I am trying to get is just:

```
[(u'55.86527,-4.2517133','Buchanan Bus Station'),
     (u'55.86068,-4.257852', 'Central Train Station'),
     (u'51.492653,-0.14765126','Victoria, Buckingham Palace Rd, Stop 10'),
     (u'51.492596,-0.14985295','Victoria Coach Station')....etc]
```

I've written plenty of regex in my time but I've never had problems like this. I am trying (believe it or not) to hide everything up to and including "new simpleInfo(' and then grab the string up to the next "'" but I can't work it out. help!

Comment: Does it need to be in a single regex? Cause it looks like you could easily parse it as json after a few search/replaces :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
re.findall(r"(?:\(new\sMicrosoft\.Maps\.Location\(([^)]+)\).+?new\ssimpleInfo\(\\?'(.+?)\\?')", test_str)
```

This regex find all occurences whether there is `\'Buchanan Bus Station\'` or `'Buchanan Bus Station'`.

Here is the **[demo](http://regex101.com/r/jH1cH9/2)**

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:\(new\sMicrosoft\.Maps\.Location\()(.+?(?=\)\,))(?:.+?).*?new\ssimpleInfo\(\\'([^'\\]+)
```

Try this.This should give you what you want.

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?:\(new\sMicrosoft\.Maps\.Location\()(.+?(?=\)\,))(?:.+?).*?new\ssimpleInfo\(\\\'([^\'\\]+)')
test_str = u"jQuery(function(){ jQuery(\'#JourneyPlanner_txtOutboundDate\').datepicker({dateFormat: \'dd/mm/yy\', firstDay: 1, beforeShowDay: function(dte){ return [((dte >= new Date(2014,9,29) && dte <= new Date(2015,0,4)) || false)]; }, minDate: new Date(2014,9,29), maxDate: new Date(2015,0,4),buttonImage: \"/images/icon_calendar.gif\", showOn: \"both\", buttonImageOnly: true}); });\njQuery(function(){ jQuery(\'#JourneyPlanner_txtReturnDate\').datepicker({dateFormat: \'dd/mm/yy\', firstDay: 1,buttonImage: \"/images/icon_calendar.gif\", showOn: \"both\", buttonImageOnly: true}); });\nEmperorBing.addCallback(function(){ var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById(\'confirm1_Map1\'), {credentials:\'Aodb7Wd7D9Kq5gKNryfW6V29yf8aw2Sbu-tXAlkH7OLJtm8zG2bQzzhDKK5zM9FE\',height: 320,width: 299, zoom: 13, mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.auto, enableClickableLogo: false , enableSearchLogo: false , showDashboard: true, showCopyright: true, showScalebar: true, showMapTypeSelector: true});\r\nEmperorBing.addMarker(map, new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(55.86527,-4.2517133), { undefined: undefined, icon:\'/images/mapmarker.gif\', width:42, height:42, anchor: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(21,21)}),new simpleInfo(\'Buchanan Bus Station\',\'Glasgow, Buchanan Bus Station - entrance to station is situated on Killermont Street. It is a short walk from George Square and within easy reach of Glasgow?s main shopping and leisure areas. Please check the bus station passenger displays for stance information "

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dP9rO4/9

Comment: This works on regex101 but the code returns an empty list in Python 2.74